# How to find usages of a Blazor component (written in razor) using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, resharper

Say I have a `MyComponent.razor` file in which a Blazor component `MyComponent` is defined. What's the best way to find the usages of this component across the solution/project?

If it's a regular class, I can simply use the "Find All References" feature in the context menu (or the "Find Usages" feature of ReSharper). But Blazor components, despite they still get compiled to classes under the hood, are usually written in Razor, where such features are not available.

Comment: A text search is the only way, I believe.  You also can't go the other way-- navigate to the definition of a component.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Actually I can go the other way with no problem using VS2019 + ReSharper :)

Comment: What I usually do is to search all text that matches the tag'ed pattern of the component. For example `MyComponent` , i will search for `<MyComponent` text. So far it never fails me unless I have the same component names on different namespaces, which is very rare to happen or minimal for me to go manual checking of search results.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for Visual Studio that has an option to find all usages of a component.

[BlazmExtension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EngstromJimmy.BlazmExtension)

[image]